# MVC controller with void method without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to call void method in MVC controller without returning blanck page with address controller/voidmethod and without using JavaScript. For example on a page clicking a button to fill a gridview with data which is on the same page.
I know if I leave the button without concrete action on click it will reload the page and perform the Index() method, but I don't think this is the proper way.

Comment: The described behaviour is what ajax requests are made for. This is possible, but you need Javascript for that.

Comment: For calling a void method you can use `[WebMethod]` tag.

Comment: Please elaborate your use case here so we can help you